# chosen scrolling is rough

Tags: scroll, jquery-chosen

Since yesterday..the latest updates..scrolling select lists seems to have a "snap-to-grid" effect. In other words it's not smooth scrolling anymore. Scrolling jumps 5 items at a time. It is worse on FF than IE. Don't know how I lost smooth scrolling in select lists formatted with Chosen.

Conferred with Chosen/Github support. Scrolling their example homepage works perfectly. 
Issue posted with project/chosen on Drupal. No response yet.

I'm using Drupal D7.26 and the latest project/chosen 7.x-2.0-beta4.

I also reloaded a backup of my site from before this latest update and scrolling works fine. I'm at a loss.

Comment: There's not a clear question here.

Answer (score 0):

Update...
Scrolling their example homepage does NOT work perfectly. Even there its choppy.

The issue was confirmed by a moderator a month ago. No fix or info since.